Trying to replicate std::complex behaviour, is the standard library lying to me or what am I missing?
I'm trying to write std::complex as an HLSL library. For this, I set out to implement the most basic functionality, starting with arithmetic operators. For finite numbers, all is well as expected. But things get weird at infinity. I won't be touching any HLSL here, it's all C++. All the following code was ran on Godbolt.
If I run the following code
std::complex<float> a(-3.0, 4.0);
std::complex<float> inf(1.0f / 0.0f, 0.0f);
a /= inf;
std::cout << a << std::endl;

Then the output will be (-0,0), which is expected. To implement this in HLSL I copied the definition for operator/= found here (same gcc version as Godbolt to make sure).
Now running this code:
std::complex<float> a(-3.0, 4.0);
std::complex<float> inf(1.0f / 0.0f, 0.0f);
float r = a.real() * inf.real() + a.imag() * inf.imag();
float n = std::norm(inf);
float imag = (a.imag() * inf.real() - a.real() * inf.imag()) / n;
float real = r / n;
std::cout << std::complex<float>(real, imag) << std::endl;

The output is now (-nan, -nan) which is different than what I got from just doing /=, but is what I expect from reading the code
Is the standard library doing something I'm not seeing in the source code, like some sort of sanity check? What am I missing?

Side note (on terminology): The "STL" is a very old library that influenced the creation of the C++ standard library. Noone uses the actual STL any more, we just use the C++ standard library.

@JesperJuhl I'm using the code gcc allegedly uses

"std::complex<float> inf(1.0f / 0.0f, 0.0f);" - You are dividing by zero. That's clearly wrong / undefined behaviour - you cannot expect anything sensible to result from that.

I can, infinite types are well defined by IEE754 and the expected (or undefined) behaviour if functions taking complex infinities is documented in cppref, such as in proj or polar functions in the complex header

Sure, infinity is a thing, like const double inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); , but dividing by zero is not the same thing. Division by zero does not have a well defined meaning in C++ AFAIK.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#:~:text=Division%20by%20zero%3A%20an%20operation,would%20be%20larger%20than%20emax).

But that's besides the point. Division by 0 is not the problem here

You are looking at the wrong definition of operator/=. You are looking at the definition for the primary class template template<typename T> complex<T>. There is a specialization template<> complex<float> with its own operator/=. This function uses the built in __complex__ float type of GCC (__complex__ here is a keyword modifying float, like unsigned in unsigned int). Essentially, GCC implements C++'s std::complex in terms of its existing support for C's _Complex/complex types (which don't exist in standard C++).
std::complex<float> a(-3.0, 4.0);
std::complex<float> inf(1.0f / 0.0f, 0.0f);
// copy a and inf into the compiler-supported complex types
__complex__ float a_prim, inf_prim;
__real__ a_prim = a.real(); __imag__ a_prim = a.imag();
__real__ inf_prim = inf.real(); __imag__ inf_prim = inf.imag();
// use primitive complex division
a_prim /= inf_prim;
std::cout << std::complex<float>(__real__ a_prim, __imag__ a_prim) << "\n";

A comment in the GCC source suggests that __complex__ division eventually does compile down to a call to library function. (Also borne out by looking at the generated code for the above snippet.) That library is libgcc, the GCC runtime library. Indeed, in libgcc, there's documentation for a function that computes a complex quotient. You can stare at the (very long) definition here. (Note that there's some macro magic going on to define all the variants of the function for all the floating point types at once).

I note that [complex.numbers.general]/3 says "If the result of a function is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined"
If I try to compile: const float infinity = 1/0;
gcc 14 gives me a warning "warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]"
clang 18 days "warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]"

IEE754 has representations for both infinity and NaN. Also, the STL mentions the expected (or undefined) behaviour when complex types take infinite or NaN values, for example in the documentation for the proj and polar functions in cppref

That warning comes from writing 1/0 which is done in integer arothmetic, then cast to float. I'm confident if you write 1.0f /0 you won't see the warning (though I'm not 100% sure)

@FranciscoJoséLetterio division by zero is always undefined behavior in C++; no exception for floating-point numbers is made. See https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4. Division by zero is also a compiler error in constant expressions despite "being defined" by IEEE-754. If you want to get infinity without UB, use std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity().
